# Not all images open up as a pop-up

Tags: php, jquery, html

I am trying to create a dynamic image popup viewer, means all images will be listed and when someone clicks on an image it will pop up and displays the whole image, but with my code only the first image in the database works. The demo can be found [**here**](http://laurels.ezyro.com/gallery2.php) and the code to the page is as follows. It includes all the php, html and jquery/javascript.

Would appreciate if someone can help me with the problem.
Thanks in advance.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
#myImg {
    border-radius: 5px;
    cursor: pointer;
    transition: 0.3s;
}

#myImg:hover {opacity: 0.7;}

/* The Modal (background) */
.modal {
    display: none; /* Hidden by default */
    position: fixed; /* Stay in place */
    z-index: 1; /* Sit on top */
    padding-top: 100px; /* Location of the box */
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%; /* Full width */
    height: 100%; /* Full height */
    overflow: auto; /* Enable scroll if needed */
    background-color: rgb(0,0,0); /* Fallback color */
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.9); /* Black w/ opacity */
}

/* Modal Content (image) */
.modal-content {
    margin: auto;
    display: block;
    width: 80%;
    max-width: 700px;
}

/* Caption of Modal Image */
#caption {
    margin: auto;
    display: block;
    width: 80%;
    max-width: 700px;
    text-align: center;
    color: #ccc;
    padding: 10px 0;
    height: 150px;
}

/* Add Animation */
.modal-content, #caption {    
    -webkit-animation-name: zoom;
    -webkit-animation-duration: 0.6s;
    animation-name: zoom;
    animation-duration: 0.6s;
}

@-webkit-keyframes zoom {
    from {-webkit-transform:scale(0)} 
    to {-webkit-transform:scale(1)}
}

@keyframes zoom {
    from {transform:scale(0)} 
    to {transform:scale(1)}
}

/* The Close Button */
.close {
    position: absolute;
    top: 15px;
    right: 35px;
    color: #f1f1f1;
    font-size: 40px;
    font-weight: bold;
    transition: 0.3s;
}

.close:hover,
.close:focus {
    color: #bbb;
    text-decoration: none;
    cursor: pointer;
}

/* 100% Image Width on Smaller Screens */
@media only screen and (max-width: 700px){
    .modal-content {
        width: 100%;
    }
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<h2>Image Modal</h2>
<p>In this example, we use CSS to create a modal (dialog box) that is hidden by default.</p>
<p>We use JavaScript to trigger the modal and to display the current image inside the modal when it is clicked on. Also note that we use the value from the image's "alt" attribute as an image caption text inside the modal.</p>
      <?php 

include("admin/db/db.php");

$select_db = "select * from gallery";
$run_events = mysql_query($select_db);
while($row=mysql_fetch_array($run_events)){

    $id = $row['id'];
      $image= $row['image'];

      ?>
<img id="myImg" src="admin/images/gallery/<?php echo $image; ?>" alt="Trolltunga, Norway" width="300" height="200">

 <?php }?> 
<!-- The Modal -->
<div id="myModal" class="modal">
  <span class="close">&times;</span>
  <img class="modal-content" id="img01">
  <div id="caption"></div>
</div>

<script>
// Get the modal
var modal = document.getElementById('myModal');

// Get the image and insert it inside the modal - use its "alt" text as a caption
var img = document.getElementById('myImg');
var modalImg = document.getElementById("img01");
var captionText = document.getElementById("caption");
img.onclick = function(){
    modal.style.display = "block";
    modalImg.src = this.src;
    captionText.innerHTML = this.alt;
}

// Get the <span> element that closes the modal
var span = document.getElementsByClassName("close")[0];

// When the user clicks on <span> (x), close the modal
span.onclick = function() { 
    modal.style.display = "none";
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: It is because you are using id tag what is suppose to be unique

Comment: @Deckerz where can i change that?

Comment: @Deckerz the id is unique but how can i make all pop-up

Comment: The ID is not unique, it is used many times. It is used on each image. ID tags should only be used on one element ever.

Comment: @Deckerz can you please advise me how i can fix this? i would really appreciate it

Comment: document.getElementById('myImg'); <-- myImg can only be used once. It will pick the first one that matches, and ignore the rest. Get images by className instead. lets say <img src=".." class="openInModal" /> and then var img = document.getElementsByClassName("openInModal");

Comment: `id="myImg"` is used repeatedly. This is illegal HTML. Element IDs must be unique. `var img = document.getElementById('myImg');` will only ever find the first tag which has that ID. It's not clear how you ever expected it to find the correct one anyway? How were you intending it to differentiate between them?

Comment: Secondly, please stop using the deprecated `mysql_` library. It was discontinued many years ago, and removed entirely in PHP7. It has documented security issues, and does not support things like prepared statements and parameterised queries which you should be using to protect your application from SQL injection attacks. You should plan to switch to using one of the `PDO` or `mysqli` libraries a.s.a.p.

Comment: @OleHaugset thaks for help but your code doesnt work

Comment: @SaqibMalik Ole's code will return a list of images. You'd have to loop through them and add a click event to each one. It's not that it doesn't work, it's just that you likely haven't used it properly. Check the MDN documentation for that method to see what it returns.

Comment: @ADyson i am new to this so dont have much knowledge, so would appreciate if you could help me out.

Comment: @SaqibMalik Actually I think the answer given below is doing exactly what I'm hinting at.

Comment: @ADyson but i dont know what a click event listener is? can you help me out i will appreciate it?

Comment: @SaqibMalik read the answer below. In your original code `img.onclick` was defining an event listener. So seemingly you didn't understand your own code? The answer just loops through all the images (instead of a single one) and does the same thing to each of the images.

Comment: @ADyson i am a php developer but dont know any javascript i got this code from W3 school

Comment: @ADyson the anser below doent work either !

Comment: @SaqibMalik in that case learn to walk before you try to run...understand the code you're looking at first before you try to change it.

Comment: What do you mean by "doesn't work"? You get an error message? Or unexpected behaviour? Did you remember to add the "imageToPopup" class to your generated image tags (to be fair the answer doesn't explicitly mention this)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to register a click event listener based on a class name used on the images. As you have used an ID and selected the element to which you bind the listener using `document.getElementById("myImg");` only one event listener is added to the first of the images.

Additionally, you should only use an HTML ID attribute value on one element in the DOM, ID values should not repeated as they are intended to be unique in the DOM.
See: [HTML ID attribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/id)

JavaScript code that will work is as follows:

```
// Get the modal
var modal = document.getElementById('myModal');

// Get the image and insert it inside the modal - use its "alt" text as a caption
var modalImg = document.getElementById("img01");
var captionText = document.getElementById("caption");


// Get the <span> element that closes the modal
var span = document.getElementsByClassName("close")[0];

// When the user clicks on <span> (x), close the modal
span.onclick = function() { 
    modal.style.display = "none";
}
// add the class 'imageToPopup' to all img elements you want to trigger the popup modal
var imgArray = document.getElementsByClassName('imageToPopup');

// Here we loop through ther array of img elements selected by class name and add an onclick event listener to each.
for(var i = 0; i<imgArray.length; i++){
  imgArray[i].onclick = function(){
        modal.style.display = "block";
        modalImg.src = this.src;
        captionText.innerHTML = this.alt;
    }
}
```

Comment: How can i register  a click event listener?

Comment: See my demo, the onclick method adds a click event listener to each of the .imageToPopup classed elements within the for loop. This just adds the same click handler code as you to for `img.onclick`, but does so for each of the array of images selected by class name.

Comment: @SebCooper potentially worth making clear that the "imageToPopup" class needs to be added to the `<img` tags before this will work.

Comment: is it possible for you to make help me with the code and making it woring or is it something really long winded?

Comment: Add the class attribute value 'imageToPopup' to each of your images to display in the modal thus: <img class="imageToPopup" ...
Then use the JS code in my example and you should see it works.

Comment: really appreciate it brother!